# React JS How to add individual functions to the numeric input arrows?

Tags: javascript, input

as we know input of type number have 2 arrows integrated (ss attached)

[image]

I will like to know if you can add different functions, one to each of the arrow.
I have for example the following code but it only adds +1 regardless of the arrow you press:

```
<input onChange = {(e) => {mas(productos.descripcion, productos.cantidad,e.target.valueAsNumber)}}
 type = 'number'
 pattern = "[0-9]*"
 required
 value = {productos.cantidad}
/>
```

I would like to add another function so that way I can use both arrows one for ++1 and the other one for --1. Any tips, help, documentation is appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onChange` just get the current input value, if you want to know if it's `++1` or `--1`, you can compare current value `e.target.valueAsNumber` with previous value `productos.cantidad`.

Comment: this can solve my issue, but I wanted to know if you could use the arrows.

Comment: No, you can't bind event on arrows.